# How to work only Day Shift?

Tags: professionalism, management, communication, team, work-time

I started this new job two weeks ago. In my online filled application, I checked the Night Shift box along with the Day Shift. I did not expect that the situation would be like now.

So the manager schedules the team on weekly basis. And, when needed, employees would get scheduled to work in a different location (under different manager).

In my first week (the week before last week), I got scheduled to work for three days, one in the day time and two late night shifts. I mentioned to my manager that I prefer to work mainly on Day Shifts but I don't mind alternating with my team. I did not mention that I am newly married and have to take care of things outside my job (But to keep simple, I don't like working at night - just like anybody else!).

This week (2nd week at work), and yesterday, I got scheduled to work 4 days, in 3 different locations, and all are Night Shifts. And when my manager sent me my schedule, a side note said: "Please tell the other managers that you prefer to work Day Shifts".

I don't like the fact that I have to coordinate/report with many managers. And that this happened after I mentioned that I can't do it.

How can I remind my manager to not schedule me Night Shifts? Taking into consideration that I don't mind doing it ONE day a week (as I think this is fair to my team).

Comment: You ticked the "night Shift" box and didn't ask what that would entail?  For me, I'd assume that means "Yes, I'm available to work nights as well as days".

Comment: @Snow it was an online app. And I ticked the "Day Shift" too, but I am working MOSTLY night. This is unfair, how to communicate that?

Comment: In my experience, anyone who is *willing* to work nights will *end up* working nights.  Simply because there are fewer people who would check that box.

Comment: Think of it this way. If you didn't tick the "night shift" box, you may not have this job now. I think you either work many night shifts or quit the job. That's reality.

Comment: To be clear, this is not unfair, you agreed to do night shift when you took the job.  Deciding after a couple of weeks that you don't want to is highly unprofessional and could and should result in your being fired at most places since they likely hired you because you agreed to do night shift work.

Comment: If you don't like working night-shifts, it doesn't seem too unreasonable to put the burden of notifying or reminding all the managers on your preference. Maybe they have some system where this can be tracked. Check with HR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an infinite amount of managers.

Just write to them all and let them know that you prefer to work more day shifts than night shifts (and let them know what ration you prefer).

See what the responses are and work with that.

Comment: Snow, I am not confused on what action should I do (just write them). I am asking to know how to do it (communicate it right, explain myself and the situation, be professional, keep the job, win)

Comment: I guess I'm oversimplifying the situation here - but whatever you said to the first manager (which didn't result in you being canned), repeat to the rest.

Comment: tell them something has changed, and you're no longer able to do nights; no fault of anyone.